# Given a (nested) view into a numpy 2D array, how to retrive the coords w.r.t. the original array

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

Consider the following:

```py
A = np.zeros((100,100))  # TODO: populate A

filt = median_filter(A, size=5)  # doesn't impact A.shape
view = filt[30:40, 30:40]
subvew = view[0:5, 0:5]
```

Is it possible to extract from `subview` the corresponding rectangle within A?

I'd like to do something like:

```
coords = get_rect(subview)
rect_A = A[coords]
```

But if I'm constantly having to pass bounding-rects thru the system the code uglifies fast.

`numpy` must store this information internally, but is it possible to access it?

PS I'm not doing anything fancy like `view = A[::2]`

PPS From reviewing the excellent answer, it looks like it should be possible to subclass numpy.ndarray, adding a `.parent` property and a `.get_global_rect()` method. But it looks like a HARD task.

Comment: Has `filt` the same spatial dimensions as `median_filter`'s input, `A`?

Comment: @Ivan Yes, I'll amend the question

Answer (score 1):

```
In [40]: x = np.arange(24).reshape(4,6)
```

`__array_interface__` is a way of viewing everything about a numpy array.

```
In [41]: x.__array_interface__
Out[41]: 
{'data': (43385712, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (4, 6),
 'version': 3}
In [42]: x.strides
Out[42]: (48, 8)
```

For a view:

```
In [43]: y = x[:3,1:4]
In [44]: y
Out[44]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [13, 14, 15]])
In [45]: y.__array_interface__
Out[45]: 
{'data': (43385720, False),
 'strides': (48, 8),
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (3, 3),
 'version': 3}
In [46]: y.base
Out[46]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23])
```

`x.base` is the same, the original `np.arange(24)`.

The key difference in `y` is the `shape`, and `data` value, which "points" 8 bytes further along.

So while one could, in theory, deduce the indexing used to create `y`, `numpy` does not have a function or method to do that for us.  Keeping track of your own "coordinates" is the best option.

Another way to put it, `y` is a `numpy.ndarray`, just like `x`.  It does not carry any extra information about how it was created.  The same applies to `z`, a view of `y`.

As for the 1d base

```
In [48]: x.base.strides
Out[48]: (8,)
In [49]: x.base.shape
Out[49]: (24,)
In [50]: x.base.__array_interface__
Out[50]: 
{'data': (43385712, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (24,),
 'version': 3}
```

Comment: So it isn't actually possible to reverse-engineer x from y. Because y offsets the memory location of x to the start of the view. And that offset isn't recorded.

Comment: It's confusing that `x.__array_interface__` shows `strides` to be `None`, whereas `x.strides` shows `(48,8)`, huh?

Comment: I think `x.strides` is a default value, easily deduced from shape and dtype.  I didn't write the code, so can't give a more profound answer.

Comment: `y.copy().strides` is (24,8) because it is no longer using the original base.  `y`, as a view, continues to use 48 to step from one row to the next.